# Automatically select the lower limit for the intensity of a color in a chart

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following snippet of code:

```
ggp <- ggplot() +
    ... +
    scale_fill_continuous(high="#112A42", low="#4FA1E0", na.value="white") + 
    ...
```

that works. I would like to change the parameter `low` in the previous function to be equal to the parameter `high` reduced by some amount, for example 50%. Something like that:

```
ggp <- ggplot() +
    ... +
    # Obviously it's wrong, but just to give you an idea of ​​what I'm looking for
    scale_fill_continuous(high="#112A42", low="#112A42"-50%, na.value="white") + 
    ...
```

Is there any way to do it?

Comment: You can use `col2rgb` to convert the high to red, green, blue values, then `rgb2hsv` to convert those to hue, saturation, value.  Then modify the hsv values as you like, and convert back to a color using `hsv`.

Comment: What do you mean by "reduced"? Do you mean made darker, made lighter, made more transparent, made less saturated? Color is not measured on a single dimension, so you need to be a bit clearer about what you mean.

Comment: You're probably looking for the function `colorspace::lighten` or `colorspace::darken`

Comment: `high=#112A42` is a dark blue. I wish `low` was a light blue.

Comment: @AllanCameron so something like `scale_fill_continuous(high = "#112A42", low = lighten("#112A42", 0.5), na.value="white")`?

Comment: Yes, LJG - exactly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if you make your life a bit over complicated here, as perhaps you can just use any online color picker and select a nice "light blue" that suits you right and replace the current low for the one you want.

However if you want to calculate it for some reason, you can convert your high and low HEX values to RGB values and take the average of those RED, GREEN and REDS. Then convert that mid color, representing your "-50%" mid value color back from RGB to HEX. Then use the calculated mid as your value for low.

```
high <- "#112A42"
low <- "#4FA1E0"

rgb_mid <- (col2rgb(high) + col2rgb(low)) / 2

mid <- rgb(t(rgb_mid), maxColorValue = 255)

mid
# [1] "#306591"
```

If you only want to define one value, the "high" you can calculate "a low", which means none of the R, G, B's can exceed 255. That ratio determines your lowest value. When you apply that to get the mean of the low and high, gives you also the 50% color based on just a high value..

*edit: rewritten in a function and handling black and a scalable factor like in lighten*

```
lighten_fun <- function(color, factor = 0.5) {
  color <- col2rgb(color)
  if (max(color) == 0) {
    low <- c(255, 255, 255)
  } else {
    low <- color * 255 / max(color)
  }
  rgb(t((color + low) * factor), maxColorValue = 255)
}

lighten_fun(color = "#112A42", factor = 0.5)
# [1] "#2966A0"
```

**note**

`lighten()` versus my method is a matter of taste, depends on what direction in your gradient you prefer to shift to. I tend to prefer to shift from dark to lighter blue and not towards the more grey area. Compare the results.

[image]

My method

[image]

`lighten()`

[image]

**Example based on Cameron's example to compare, just note colors are just a matter of preference**

```
p <- ggplot(within(mtcars, car <- rownames(mtcars)),aes(car, mpg, fill = disp)) +
  geom_col() +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1, vjust = 0.5))


p + scale_fill_continuous(high = "#112A42", low = lighten_fun("#112A42", 0.5), na.value="white")
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can lighten or darken arbitrary colors using `colorspace::darken` and `colorspace::lighten`. For example, let's define this little wrapper function:

```r
library(ggplot2)

scale_fill_mygradient <- function(color = "gray", lighten = 0.5, ...) {
  
  scale_fill_gradient(high = color, 
                      low  = colorspace::lighten(color, lighten),
                      ...)
}
```

And a plot to test it on:

```
p <- ggplot(within(mtcars, car <- rownames(mtcars)), 
            aes(car, mpg, fill = disp)) +
  geom_col() +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1, vjust = 0.5))
```

Now we can do

```r
p + scale_fill_mygradient("blue")
```

[image]

and

```r
p + scale_fill_mygradient("#112A42")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-07-20 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: nice solution,  for those who prefer another direction or expected "a more blueish color", see my note on the difference.